# Reusable parametric css with styled components

Tags: javascript, typescript, mixins, styled-components

I'm using styled-components library in my react app and I've come across an interesting problem I wasn't able to find an elegant solution to online. What I want to achieve is to have a reusable piece of code, maybe similar to sass mixins, that would allow me to extend all my buttons with code that animates background darken on hover.

```
const DarkenHover = css<{ active?: boolean; normalColor: string; activeColor: string }>`
    background-color: ${p => (p.active ? p.normalColor : p.activeColor)};
    &:hover {
        background-color: ${p => darken(0.1)(p.active ? p.normalColor : p.activeColor)};
    }
    transition: background-color .1s ease-in;
`;

const FooButton = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    ${p => DarkenHover({
        active: p.active,
        normalColor: "red",
        activeColor: "blue",
    })}
`;

const FooButton = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    ${p => DarkenHover({
        active: p.active,
        normalColor: "white",
        activeColor: "green",
    })}
`;
```

This obviously is not valid syntax but it demonstrates my use case. How can I use this `DarkenHover` css object with attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the styles in a var and reuse later.

```
const animation = css`
 background-color: ${p => p.active ? ThemeColors.backgroundDark : "white"};
    &:hover {
        background-color: ${p =>  darken(0.1)(p.active ? p.normalColor : p.activeColor)};
    }
    transition: background-color .1s ease-in;
 }
`;
```

The when you use it in another component, it should be able to access its props:

```
const FooButton = styled.div`
    ${animation};
`
```

Also to be able to have separate props per each styled components, those can be passed via `attrs` method:

```
const FooButton = styled.div.attrs({normalColor: '#000000' })`
   ${animation}
`;
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. How do I pass different properties for different uses of this css object (the `normalColor` and `activeColor` props from the example).

Comment: You can pass them to the component as props.when you render it. `<FooButton normalColor='#000000' />`.

Comment: That's not the solution either. I would like to define them for the styled component and not for it's every usage.

Comment: If you want those per styled component, you can pass the props via `attrs`: `const FooButton = styled.div.attrs({normalColor: '#000000' })`
    ${animation};
`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be working, but they have to have matching names. Is that the best solution though?

Comment: Can't think of anything better. Maybe if you make `animation` a function that will accept the props and call it like `${animation(props)};` it could work, but doesn't seem the cleanest option either. The styled-components output is basically interpolated JS string, so you can manipulate it in various ways.